# How many ways can I arrange ROONEY KIM if R and K can't be next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

Please help. Me and my friend are on a debate on who is right.

1. How many ways can I arrange ROONEY KIM if R and K can't be next to each other? My friend said it's $9!/2! -2!(8!)= 181440$. I said it's $9!/2! - 8!/2!$.
2. How many ways can you arrange ARRANGED If N and D can't be together?

Please help us resolve this conflict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- $\frac{9!}{2!}$ would be the answer if the R&K rule did not apply, because of the two Os
- The number of arrangements with R immediately followed by K would be $\frac{8!}{2!}$ treating RK as a single letter
- The number of arrangements with K immediately followed by R would be $\frac{8!}{2!}$ treating KR as a single letter
- So the number of arrangements if R and K can't be next to each other is  $\frac{9!}{2!}- 2\frac{8!}{2!}$

(ARRANGEMENT does not have a D in it)

Comment: I meant ARRANGED sorry

Comment: @QuantumPi For ARRANGED do the same thing without the N&D rule (2 As and 2 Rs) and subtract as necessary

Answer (score 0):

You should learn more than one way of attacking a problem, especially if the methods are equally easy, so I am solving by a different method.

There are $(7!/2!)$ arrangements of the letters without the $R$ and $K$

The two letters taken out can be inserted back into the $8$ gaps between the letters (including gaps at the ends) in $8\cdot7$ places, thus $(7!/2!)\cdot8\cdot7$ ways

Similarly, for $N$ and $D$ to not be next to each other in $ARRANGED, [6!/(2!2!)]\cdot 7\cdot6$ ways